# Си запись в файлы два и более раз подряд. Не срабатывает fgets

Tags: c

При вызове функции в первый раз все ок! Файл создается и записывается должным образом.
Но при попытке вызвать функцию еще раз она создает просто пустой файл(
Пробовал читать посимвольно - та же история
Чистка буфера не помогает(

```
void from_prog_to_file(char path_to_prog[], char path_to_temp_file[]){
    FILE *prog = popen(path_to_prog, "r");
    FILE *temp = fopen(path_to_temp_file, "w");
    char buffer[256];
    while((fgets(buffer, 256, prog)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
        fputs(buffer, temp);
    }
    fclose(temp);
    fclose(prog);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете `fclose` для закрытия потока полученного через `popen`, для него нужно использовать `pclose`.

Примеры: [GNU Pipe to a Subprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!